# how to convert json values in comma separated string using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have following JSON string :

```js
{"name":"Marine Lines","location_id":3},{"name":"Ghatkopar","location_id":2}
```

I want location_id as

3,2

Comment: Is that JSON string enclosed as an array? i.e. surrounded by `[]`?

Comment: try to use a library for this propouse, http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: @Mitul - I've rolled back your edit because without hearing back from the OP I don't think we can just assume that their input string is different to what they've said it is. (Though obviously as is it is not valid JSON.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simple:

```js
var data = [{"name":"Marine Lines","location_id":3},{"name":"Ghatkopar","location_id":2}]
var result = data.map(function(val) {
  return val.location_id;
}).join(',');

console.log(result)
```

I assume you wanted a string, hence the `.join(',')`, if you want an array simply remove that part.

Comment: FYI, `.join` by defaults join values by comma.

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, but I added it for clarification.

Answer (score 5):

You could add brackets to the string, parse the string ([`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)) and map ([`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) the property and the join ([`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)) the result.

```js
var string = '{"name":"Marine Lines","location_id":3},{"name":"Ghatkopar","location_id":2}',
    array = JSON.parse('[' + string + ']'),
    result = array.map(function (a) { return a.location_id; }).join();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: OP had edited the question to add the enclosing square brackets.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj - That edit wasn't by the OP, and the OP hasn't replied to a query about it, so for now I've rolled that edit back.

Answer (score 1):

```js
obj=[{"name":"Marine Lines","location_id":3}, {"name":"Ghatkopar","location_id":2}]
var res = [];
for (var x  in obj)
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x))
    res.push(obj[x].location_id);
console.log(res.join(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var json = [{"name":"Marine Lines","location_id":3},{"name":"Ghatkopar","location_id":2}];

var locationIds = [];
for(var object in json){
  locationIds.push(json[object].location_id);
}

console.log(locationIds.join(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also look into `.reduce` and create a string manually

```js
var d = [{"name":"Marine Lines","location_id":3},{"name":"Ghatkopar","location_id":2}]

var location_id_str = d.reduce(function(p, c) {
  return p ? p + ',' + c.location_id : c.location_id
},'');

console.log(location_id_str)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there are more than two objects in the array.

Comment: Perfect Solution. Mine more than 500 values, its took only 100ms time .

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
    var obj = [{"name":"Marine Lines","location_id":3},{"name":"Ghatkopar","location_id":2}];
    var output = obj.map( function(item){
      return item.location_id;
    });
    console.log( output.join(",") )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{"name":"Marine Lines","location_id":3},{"name":"Ghatkopar","location_id":2}];

var location_array = [];
for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )
{
  location_array.push( arr[i].location_id );
}//for

var location_string = location_array.join(",");
console.log(location_string);
```

**Note: You may need to use JSON.parse() if the `arr` is in string format initially.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for..of` loop

```js
var arr = [{
  "name": "Marine Lines",
  "location_id": 3
}, {
  "name": "Ghatkopar",
  "location_id": 2
}];

var res = [];

for ({location_id} of arr) {res.push(location_id)};

console.log(res);
```